Create query on SAP 4/Hana view with SAS e.g
I try to create a query on SAS view, based on a SAP 4/Hana table.
I get the following error:
ERROR: Unable to transcode data to/from UCS-2 encoding.
How can I change the encoding?
I've tried to copy the view as a data table in my work folder, and tried the query, without success.
I'm using this SAS e.g. version:
8.3 Update 8 (8.3.8.206) (32-Bit)
Thank you in advance.
Kind regards,
Ben

Is your SAS session using a single byte encoding? What is the system option ENCODING set to for your SAS session? %put %sysfunc(getoption(encoding));  If you want to work with characters other than normal 7-bit ASCII character then it will work much better if you start SAS using UTF-8 as the encoding.  Looks like you showed the version of Enterprise Guide you are using to run your SAS programs.  What version of SAS are you running? %put &=sysvlong;

Hi Tom, thanks for the post. I've checked your commands. My SAS session uses LATIN9 encoding. The SAS Version is SYSVLONG=9.04.01M8P022223.

Ask your SAS support team how to initiate SAS using unicode support (encoding=utf-8).  That should help with dealing with characters that do not exist in the LATIN9 encoding.
